# mod_rewrite how to show images in a certain dir

Tags: css, mod-rewrite, apache

I am starting to use mod_rewrite and would like to know if the below is possible...

`RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)/$ /test.php?x=$1 [NC,L]`

That works as expected however, once the HTML generates I use relative paths to images/stylesheets etc such as `<img src="include/image.jpg" />` which now no longer shows.

How can I get around this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to add a rule to [skip requests that end in standard image file suffixes](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/1972.htm):

```
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ - [NC,S=1]
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)/$ /test.php?x=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I don't think this will help the OP: their problem is that the browser is trying to request `/test/include/image.jpg`, when the actual URL path of the image is `/include/image.jpg`.

Comment: Oh, I read it that the images are in `/test/include/` and those requests are incorrectly being rewritten to `/test.php?x=include/image.jpg` I see how it could be read the other way as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities:

- Don't use relative paths.
- Add a `<base>` tag to your HTML.
- Rewrite the image URLs too:

```
RewriteRule ^test/include/(.*)$ /include/$1 [NC,L]
```